# Asp.net MVC pass input value from view to controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I've never worked with both asp.net and mvc.

I need to create simple registration form but I can't pass value from input to controller. I'm not using model and if I just could get values from view to controller there is server side function in my controller which will add inputs to database.

I searched a lot but there is always answers with using razor and `html.beginform` etc. and I don't have any of them.

Here is my view:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Main.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="TitleContent" runat="server">
Index
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
<table width="100%">
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td valign="top" style="width:300px">
            <fieldset>
                <legend><b>Registration</b></legend>
                <table class="submit">
                    <tr>
                        <td>Customer Code:</td>
                        <td style="width: 50%">                                
                            <%: Html.TextBox("cbCode")%>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Card No:</td>
                        <td>
                            <%: Html.TextBox("cardNo")%>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>E-Code:</td>
                        <td>
                            <%: Html.TextBox("pswrd")%>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>E-Token:</td>
                        <td>
                            <%: Html.TextBox("tokenId")%>
                        </td>
                    </tr>                        
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <button type="submit" onclick="tokenSubmit('POST');" class="btn">
                                Submit</button>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </fieldset>                
                <legend><b>Result</b></legend>
                <div id="Result">
                </div>
            </fieldset>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</asp:Content>
```

My controller:

```
namespace Branch.Controllers
{
public class CardEcodeController : Controller
{
    //
    // GET: /CardEcode/

    public ActionResult Index()
    {            

        long cbCode = value from input;
        long cardNo = value from input;
        long tokenId = value from input;
        long pswrd = value from input;

        //using functions written in server side
        RegisterClient reg = new RegisterClient();
        reg.InsertToken(cbCode,cardNo,tokenId,pswrd);           


        return View();
    }       

}

}
```

I think my MVC version is 2 or 3.

Comment: [Intro to ASP.NET MVC](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/getting-started-with-mvc/getting-started-with-mvc-part1)

Comment: This requires front-end coding with javascript to do. You can get that for "free" when you use viewmodels. I strongly recommend you to watch into the tutorials above that Stephen recommends or the videos I posted in my post. I can help you out with a "poor-mans validation" script. But for that you should do a separate post about it. Also another benefit for you to use viewmodels over your current approach, is that when you return views like you do now the parameters will be null, as mvc is stateless.

Comment: I've removed the second question from this old post - please ask only one question per post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I strongly recommend you to read up on working with [MVC](http://www.asp.net/mvc/videos/mvc-2/how-do-i/creating-a-tasklist-application-with-aspnet-mvc). The version you are using is MVC2 most likely. If you can I would do the project in MVC3 or MVC4 to use Razor syntax. The quick answer to your question is this.

```
<%using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "CardEcode", FormMethod.Post)){%>
    <table width="100%">
       <!-- table code here -->
    </table>
<% } %>
```

For your controller you have to make a post action.

```
public ActionResult Index()
{            
     return View();
} 

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(long cbCode, long cardNo, long tokenId, long pswrd)
{            
      //using functions written in server side
      RegisterClient reg = new RegisterClient();
      reg.InsertToken(cbCode,cardNo,tokenId,pswrd);           


      return View();
}
```